# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unobserve') in vue-slick-carousel with dynamic content

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I'm filling in vue-slick-carousel with dynamic data using graphql and apollo.

this is graphql query with i18n

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const GetSlider = gql`
  query GetSlider($locale: I18NLocaleCode) {
    sliderConfigs(locale: $locale) {
      data {
        id
      }
      data {
        attributes {
          title
          subTitle
          sliderImage {
            data {
              attributes {
                url
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

the slider component

```
<script>
import VueSlickCarousel from "vue-slick-carousel";
import "vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css";
import { GetSlider } from "../graphql/GetSlider";
import ContactBtn from "./ContactBtn";

export default {
  name: "Slider",
  components: { VueSlickCarousel, ContactBtn },
  data() {
    return {
      sliderConfigs: [],
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        autoplay: true,
      },
    };
  },
  apollo: {
    sliderConfigs: {
      prefetch: true,
      query: GetSlider,
      variables() {
        return { locale: this.$i18n.locale };
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>

<template>
  <section class="banner-slide">
    <VueSlickCarousel :data="sliderConfigs" v-bind="settings">
      <div
        v-for="sliderConfigs in sliderConfigs.data"
        v-bind:key="sliderConfigs.id"
        class="banner-area bg_cover d-flex align-items-center"
        :style="{
          backgroundImage: `url(
    'http://localhost:1337${sliderConfigs.attributes.sliderImage.data.attributes.url}'
  )`,
        }"
      >
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="banner-slide-number">
                <span>0{{ sliderConfigs.id }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
              <div class="banner-content">
                <span data-animation="fadeInDown" data-delay=".1s">
                  <!-- <img src="/assets/images/logo_white_small.svg" alt="" /> -->
                  {{ sliderConfigs.attributes.title }}</span
                >
                <h1 data-animation="fadeInLeft" data-delay=".5s" class="title">
                  {{ sliderConfigs.attributes.subTitle }}
                </h1>
                <ContactBtn data-animation="fadeInLeft" data-delay="1s" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </VueSlickCarousel>
  </section>
</template>
```

at the same time, the web page I am working on contains multiple language options. The main problem is that when I change the language,

> the Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unobserve') error
> occurs

while the page is loading, but when I refresh the page, the data comes back in a healthy way. Is there a point I missed?

Comment: where or what is the stacktrace for the error?  I would expect to see "unobserve" somewhere in the code indicating the error location but I see none in your snippet.  Usually this kind of error is an indication of some async operation happening and the template is trying to use as of yet undefined async data which causes it to immediately throw an error.

Comment: the component
wrapping it in a div and adding v-if="sliderConfigs.data" fixed my display problem @yoduh

```<div v-if="sliderConfigs.data">
          <VueSlickCarousel/>
   </div>```

Answer (score 1):

the component
wrapping it in a div and adding v-if="sliderConfigs.data" fixed my display problem

```
<div v-if="sliderConfigs.data">           
     <VueSlickCarousel/>    
</div>
```